# Ocultar opcion de mi menu dependiendo el usuario que igrese

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, css

1.como puedo ocultar una opción de mi menu a todos los usuarios excepto a un usuario que es el administrador?

```
2.este es una parte de mi codigo el cual quiero bloquear si el usuario que ingreso no es el administrador, pero me la oculta con todos los usuarios.
```

````
  if (!$_SESSION["sesion_valida"]) {
      header("location: login.php");
      exit();
  }
  ?>

  <?php 
  if ($_SESSION['usuario']=="usuario_admi") { ?>

    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="Index.php?seccion=Administracion">Administracion</a>
    </li> 
  <?php } ?>```
````

Comment: Por un casual no has abierto la session al principio de tu código?

Comment: ¿Ya verificaste que `"usuario_admi"` esté bien escrito?

Answer (score 0):

Veo que estas un poco nuevo al igual que yo y por lo poco que entendi (porque lo hice) no creaste roles de usuario etc.. asi que si quieres mostrar tu menu solo al administrador simplemente edita un pedazo de tu codigo y has esto, suponiendo que el nombre del administrador es "usuario_admi" como lo estas colocando arriba has esto

```
<!-- Aqui suponemos que al validar la sesión del usuario guardaste su nombre en la variable 
SESSION 'usuario' si quieres comprobar que lo esta guardando agrega este pequeño código después 
del body de tu pagina <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']; ?> y si aparece el nombre del usuario 
(que indicamos que es "usuario_admi") pues no deberías tener problemas -->

<?php 
  if ($_SESSION['usuario']=="usuario_admi") { ?> 
<!-- Aqui solo aparece este <li> si el usuario es "usuario_admi", el codigo se interpreta como "si la variable session usuario es igual a usuario_admi muestrale esto" -->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="Index.php?seccion=Administracion">Administracion</a>
    </li> 
  <?php
endif;
 } ?>
<!-- Aqui termina el if -->
```